# Is there a command to rotate all files that end with a particular few characters 90 degrees CCW

Tags: image, shell, terminal, console, command

I have around 100000 images, but only a certain amount of them I require to be rotated. All of the ones that need to be rotated end with the same characters however i.e. they end with .tif.png. Is there a shell command that I could use to filter through all of the files and locate only the ones that contain ".tif.png" and rotate all of those images 90 degrees counter-clockwise? I am not super familiar with shell commands FYI :)

Comment: on unix, you can do something like `find -name '*.tif.png' -exec gm mogrify -rotate -90 {} \;` (`gm` comes from graphicsmagick package)

Comment: Do I have to download that package or can I just type that in?

Comment: Yeah, when I type it it says "find: ‘gm’: No such file or directory"

Comment: https://repology.org/project/graphicsmagick/versions

Comment: I'm using cygwin (on windows). How would I install it on there?

Comment: https://cygwin.com/install.html#add-package